# Need CURL request to fool server into thinking flash is installed

Tags: php, flash, curl

I was wondering how you might be able to update a CURL (PHP) request to fool the receiving server into thincking you are a genuine browser which has the flash plugin installed.

I am requesting a page which has a flash video. What I receive back is an image suggesting I should install the flash plugin.

Has anyone come across this before and could I send the request with altered headers to fool the server into thinking the request is coming from a genuine flash plugin installed browser?

Thanks.

Comment: Are you sure it isn't sending that to everyone? Most Flash embeds include a fallback image like this.

Comment: @ceejayoz Yes it probably is. Although it doesn't when I visit the page in a browser. The video does not appear with JavaScript turned off so as you suggest it is a fallback image.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Flash isn't exposed through request headers.  There is nothing to fool.

As ceejayoz pointed out, embedding Flash is usually a progressive enhancement.  A page is sent with some fallback content (such as text saying you don't have flash), and then that fallback is replaced with Flash by JavaScript.

Comment: Right. Makes sense. No Javascript = Default/Fallback image.